# Distribute/float content boxes to equally-height columns via CSS

Tags: html, css, grid, css-float

I got some content boxes with different heights, they're floated. Unfortunately, there's a lot of wasted space in between. Take the following example (https://jsfiddle.net/mzqb7mzm/ if you wanna see it live and play):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            width: 320px;
        }
        div {
            margin: 2px;
            width: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #aaa;
        }

        .box {
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box" style="height:  50px; ">1. box</div>
    <div class="box" style="height: 300px; ">2. box</div>
    <div class="box" style="height: 150px; ">3. box</div>
    <div class="box" style="height: 200px; ">4. box</div>
    <div class="box" style="height: 150px; ">5. box</div>
    <div class="box" style="height: 100px; ">6. box</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I ensure that e.g. box 4 or 5 (or any other) fill the space below box 1 instead of producing this large whitespace? Already saw some solutions like Thumblr, but they're using Javascript. I'm interested in a purely CSS (perfect would be CSS2) solution. Is this even possible?

Comment: You can use masonry https://jsfiddle.net/mzqb7mzm/1/

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'm interested in a CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say it, but it is technically impossible to do this in CSS. I also have had this problem and could not find a solution (changing displays does not work, extra divs does not, etc.).

If anyone does still know a solution, I would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the HTML markup, just place the `.box`'s in columns like:

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="box" style="height:  50px; ">1. box</div>
  <div class="box" style="height: 150px; ">5. box</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="box" style="height: 300px; ">2. box</div>
  <div class="box" style="height: 100px; ">6. box</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="box" style="height: 150px; ">3. box</div>
  <div class="box" style="height: 200px; ">4. box</div>
</div>
```

Then float the columns left:

```
.col {
  float: left;
}
```

With that, your render will now look like:

```css
body {
  width: 320px;
}

.box {
  margin: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  text-align: center;
}

.col {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="box" style="height:  50px; ">1. box</div>
  <div class="box" style="height: 150px; ">5. box</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="box" style="height: 300px; ">2. box</div>
  <div class="box" style="height: 100px; ">6. box</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="box" style="height: 150px; ">3. box</div>
  <div class="box" style="height: 200px; ">4. box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like good old tables layout ... there's no sense in using float at all, when I have to distribute it manually to my columns. I even might have no idea about the number of columns (it's a float), and have no idea about the height of a box.

Comment: @000 well, then you can't do it with CSS